# How to get from dataframe to list of dictionaries that contain a list

Tags: python, pandas

Hopefully anybody can help me with this:

I have a database connection that writes directly into a dataframe. However, I would like to be able to convert it to a list of dictionaries that also include a list. So, in my example, from `df` to `list_of_dict`:

```
import pandas

# FROM:
df = pandas.DataFrame({"ID":["A1","B2","C3","D4"], "x":[1,1,2,2], "Length":[10,11,6,8], "Width":[1,1.3,2,1], "Height": [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]})


#TO:
list_of_dict = [{"ID":"A1", "x":1, "Size":[10,1,0.5]},
                {"ID":"B2", "x":1, "Size":[11,1.3,0.5]},
                {"ID":"C3", "x":2, "Size":[6,2,0.5]},
                {"ID":"D4", "x":2, "Size":[8,1,0.5]}]
```

The list `Size` would consist of of `Length`,`Width` and `Height`.

If've looked for solutions online but they don't seem to tackle this specific challenge. As I'm new to lists and dictionaries all help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
df['Size'] = df[['Length', 'Width', 'Height']].values.tolist()

list_of_dict = df[['ID', 'x', 'Size']].to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: Great! Didn't expect you could store lists in dataframes as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

`orient` parameters control the output format